# C#: What is this statement doing? dynObj.@switch == 1 ? true : false

Tags: c#, dynamic

I recently took over some code and came a across a statement that I wasn't sure what it was doing so I decided to post it.

currCarbon.CleanGeneration = (**dynObj.@switch** == 1 ? true : false);

Since 'dynObj' is a dynamic object holding a json value, is it checking if 'dynObj' contains a 'Switch' key / value?

Thanks for you help!

```
        dynamic dynObj = GetValues();

        if (dynObj != null) //json string from API
        {
          // Read the first record's carbon index
          var prevCarbon = _dbContext.WatttimeApilog.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();

          if (prevCarbon == null) //NO previous carbon value from database
          {
            //Plug in default values
            currCarbon.Percentage = defaultPercent;
            currCarbon.CleanGeneration = false;
            currCarbon.Rating = defaultRating;
            currCarbon.ValidUntil = DateTime.UtcNow;
            insertFlag = true;
          }
          else
          {
            currCarbon.Percentage = dynObj.percent;
            currCarbon.CleanGeneration = (dynObj.@switch == 1 ? true : false);
            currCarbon.Rating = Convert.ToByte(dynObj.rating);
            currCarbon.ValidUntil = dynObj.validUntil;
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's setting `CleanGeneration` to true or false based on whether or not `@switch` is equal to one via a ternary operator.

EDIT: The code isn't the most clean and can be shortened to just `currCarbon.CleanGeneration = dynObj.@switch == 1;`

Linked is docs on the ternary operator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Why the .@?  Why not just dynObj.switch?

Comment: That's because `switch` is a keyword so you cannot have a variable named just `switch` so you add a `@` in front to make it a name and not a keyword.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you